# Why in the logcat suggested “FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION”

Tags: android

I have a project after debugging on the real machine found that the beginning can accept the data, in the logcat shows receive data, but phone will stack finally, the logcat will show the following error:

```
08-22 15:33:41.782 1053-1121/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-22 15:33:41.782 1053-1121/? W/BroadcastQueue: Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=com.android.smartphone.SmartphoneSystemActivity flg=0x10 (has extras) }
                                             android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:502)
                                                 at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ApplicationThreadNative.java:1104)
                                                 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.performReceiveLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:520)
                                                 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.deliverToRegisteredReceiverLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:610)
                                                 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:721)
                                                 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:179)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I searched on the Internet，somebody said that it is because the transmission of data over 1Mb,or someone uses Bitmap or something. but I passed the data is not so big and no picture, and at first data can be transmitted,so I do not know where is wrong, attached to my key code:

about send Broadcast:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.smartphone.SmartphoneSystemActivity");
intent.putExtra("4_ch_data", EEG_data);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

about receiver Broadcast:

```
public class newStress extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.newstress);
    Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    msgReceiver = new MsgReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.android.smartphone.SmartphoneSystemActivity");
    registerReceiver(msgReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public class MsgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int[] data = new int[4];
        double[] ddata = new double[4];
        int i;

        data = intent.getIntArrayExtra("4_ch_data");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ddata[i] = (double) (data[i]);
            if (ddata[i] <= 8388607) {

                ddata[i] = ((ddata[i] + 8388608) * 2.4 / 8388607);
            } else {
                ddata[i] = ((ddata[i] - 8388608) * 2.4 / 8388607);
            }
            // Log.i("display", "data: "+ddata[i]);
        }
        Process(ddata);

    }
}

protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    Intent bluetoothserivce = new Intent (this,BluetoothActivity.class);
    stopService(bluetoothserivce);
    unregisterReceiver(msgReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}



}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is EGG_data?

Comment: Is a array,defined as ：int [] EEG_data =new int[4];@Randyka Yudhistira